# Showing orange border only through tab navigation

Tags: html, focus

**Issue :** I have added an "tabindex" attribute for some of the divs, so that they are accessible via tab key keyboard navigation. But now it gives a bad user experience by giving a orange order as soon as the div is clicked. I would like to show the orange border only when the user navigated to the div using the keyboard not when he clicked on it.

Following JSFiddle link that illustrate the issue. The button will get orange border only through tab navigation where as the div will get a orange border as soon as it is clicked.
How can I simulate a similar behavior of a button to a div?

http://jsfiddle.net/tsuTs/

**Note :** I know that adding `outline :none` css to :focus state would remove the outline, but then it would also remove it when the user navigate to the div using a keyboard.

Can someone help me with this.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You might wanna consider using jquery, remove the outline as you described, then add a keyup event when tab is pressed, and if your field is focued, change back outline to default.

Comment: @Sony : Thanks, I am actually interested in knowing the internal implementation of a button/input button, and if there exists an easier solution. i.e. through CSS.